# SQLAlchemy 2.0 option for LOCK TABLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking

Does SQLAlchemy 2.0 has any options to perform `LOCK TABLE table_name` sql query?
Seems, that SQLAlchemy docs lack that information.

As an example I would like to perform

```
create_engine().connect().execute(text("LOCK TABLE table_name"))
create_engine().connect().execute(text("DELETE ..."))
create_engine().connect().execute(text("INSERT ..."))
create_engine().connect().commit()
```

Comment: SQLA doesn't provide a way of doing this, other than issuing commands via `text`, as you are already doing.

Comment: The answer above should be accepted. In fact you could try using `Session().connection(execution_options={"isolation_level": "SERIALIZABLE"})`, which makes your transaction fully isolated from outer changes during that transaction, however once `commit`ed then you could encounter `serialization errors`, since other transactions could also have done some work by that time, which is not compatible with your transaction's changes. So, indeed, for "disabling" MVCC for the database, while executing a transaction you should do what you did before, i.e explicit locking

Answer (score -1):

SQLAlchemy 2.0 does not have a built-in option to perform a LOCK TABLE statement. However, raw SQL can be executed directly using the execute() method offered by both the Engine and Session objects., including LOCK TABLE.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database')

connection = engine.connect()

# Lock the table
connection.execute(text("LOCK TABLE table_name"))

# Delete all rows from the table
connection.execute(text("DELETE FROM table_name"))

# Insert a new row into the table
connection.execute(text("INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES ('New row')"))

# Commit the changes
connection.commit()

# Close the connection
connection.close()
```

It is important to note that using the raw() method can be dangerous if you are not careful. Make sure to validate the SQL query before executing it, and avoid using it to execute dynamic SQL queries. If you need to lock tables on a regular basis, I would recommend to use a database-specific locking mechanism. For example, PostgreSQL has a built-in locking mechanism that you can use to lock tables before performing operations on them.

Comment: " it is recommended" -> can you provide a link to this recommendation?

Comment: @Kihara where is that `raw()` method in your code you're talking about? :) Also use `context manager` i.e `with statement` for managing resources

Comment: @ojacomarket I apologize for the mistakes in my previous response. After further consideration and feedback, I've realized that my initial answer had errors and have updated it.